# Animation Completed fires slightly to soon

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a couple of animations which run one by one to create some kind of transition to the next page. The last animation (a `DoubleAnimation`) is the last animation executed. As soon as the animation is done, data needs to be loaded. I am using the `Completed` event in this case.
It looks like this event kicks in slightly to soon and creates a hiccup in this last animation. Is there something that might resolve this?
For example:

```cs
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
anim.To = 200; 
anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
anim.Completed += ((s,e) => { LoadData(); });
element.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.WidthProperty, anim);
```

The `LoadData` function is manipulating the UI and thus need to be executed within the UI thread. (Which is causing the hiccup because it got executed slightly to soon).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps in your situation, but you may try to first stop the animation, then set the animated element's Width, and finally call LoadData:

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimation
{
    To = 200,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
};

anim.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    element.Width = anim.To.Value;
    LoadData();
};

element.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, anim);
```